# Медленно работает Gitlab.

Tags: git, gitlab, centos

После обновления Gitlabа, стали долго загружаться страницы в браузере, хотя до обновление было все моментально. В чем может быть проблема? Обновлял по [этому](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/upgrader.md) мануалу.

Версия Gitlaba до обновления 7.0.0, после 7.5.3. Сервер локальный. Centos 7. Пробовал с разных браузеров. БД MySQL.

Заметил в `htop`, что когда обновляешь страницу команда

```
unicorn_rails master ../gitalb/config unicorn.rb
```

грузит процессор до 100%.

Еще замечание, если заходить на gitlab с внешки то страницы загружаются нормально, авторизируется, проц не грузит. Но нет меню, рядом с поиском. А вот если из локальной сети то страничка грузится долго, и нагрузка возрастает, и меню есть. Вот такие дела!

Comment: плохой вопрос. Как минимум нужно указать:

- версию гитлаба до и после
- на каком сервере он расположен (домашний или выделенный у прова)
- версию оси на сервере
- версию оси и браузера, которыми Вы пользуетесь.

Comment: Вроде все указал.